# Qual o significado da letra "T" no profissional T-Shaped?

Tags: significado

Desde os [anos 90](http://www.administradores.com.br/artigos/academico/t-shaped-professional-e-design-institucional/71492/) vem se falando muito no profissional T-Shaped ou Modelo-T.

[Nesse artigo da Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/?toURL=http://www.forbes.com/sites/andyboynton/2011/10/18/are-you-an-i-or-a-t/&refURL=https://www.google.com.br/&referrer=https://www.google.com.br/), fala sobre dois tipos de profissionais:

> One can be shaped either like an "I” (think narrow and tight) or a "T"
>   (think extended). The I-shaped professional is highly versed in a
>   specific area of expertise and learns by drilling more deeply into a
>   particular field. The T-shaped person has broader skills and knowledge
>   and learns by linking up different perspectives from different
>   specialties.

Ou seja, o profissional I-Shaped é altamente capacitado em um área especifica. Já o T-Shaped tem habilidades e conhecimentos mais amplos e aprende, ligando perspectivas diferentes de diferentes especialidades.

Pela definição de T-Shaped penso que o `T` a conexão entre o conhecimento sobre diversos assuntos (sendo a parte de cima do T) e o conhecimento em algo específico, sendo a parte de baixo representando a base.

Minha dúvida é: Estou correta nesse pensamento ou existe um significado para o `T` na palavra T-Shaped?

*Obs.: A palavra T-Shaped, apesar de ser em inglês é utilizada também no português, podendo ser encontrada também como Modelo-T.*

Comment: Isto parece ser uma pergunta sobre língua inglesa e não portuguesa. Encontras essas expressões em textos em português?

Comment: Sim, no português também a palavra também é T-Shaped, mas já vi artigos falando sobre Modelo-T.

Comment: Então, não queres incluir alguns desses textos; como está não se percebe que a expressão é usada em português, que é o que nos interessa aqui.

Comment: @Jacinto, é mais comum encontrarmos a palavra T-Shaped em inglês do que Modelo-T, que seria em português.

Comment: Isso é bobagem. Foi esse sujeito que inventou essa praga: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-shaped_skills

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub><sup>Aviso: Eu tenho um ódio profundo por este tipo de palavras. Mas claro faco uma resposta decente á mesma.</sup></sub>

> Pela definição de T-Shaped penso que o T a conexão entre o
>   conhecimento sobre diversos assuntos (sendo a parte de cima do T) e o
>   conhecimento em algo específico, sendo a parte de baixo representando
>   a base.

É isso mesmo. É fácil de observar a mesma afirmação/analogia [pelas várias imagens dísponiveis no google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22t+shaped%22&lr=lang_pt&hl=pt-PT&tbs=lr:lang_1pt&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDup7Lvc7RAhVLDxoKHZwID4gQ_AUICCgB&biw=1920&bih=1070), ficam aqui algumas.

[image]
[image]

[Conforme as pesquisas do google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&as_q=&as_epq=t+shaped&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=lang_pt&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) (configurado para apresentar mais resultados na lingua portuguesa) a expressão t-shaped é normalmente usada no contexto de trabalho, para referir uma qualidade que supostamente é bom um empregado ter.

É também interessante poder verificar que só na primeira página é possível encontrar 4 ocorrências no ramo de IT/programacão

Comment: Na área de T.I. são conhecidos como desenvolvedores [full stack](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/52451/51124)